# ValueError: Unknown URI

Tags: solidity, python, infura, brownie, visual-studio-code

I'm following a solidity tutorial from Patrick Collins and when trying to run the following:

```
brownie run scripts/get_weth.py --network mainnet-fork
```

I get an error:

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

AaveBrowniePyProject is the active project.
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    web3.connect(host, active.get("timeout", 30))
  File "C:\Users\Dev, line line, in in
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unknown URI - must be a path to an IPC socket, a websocket beginning with 'ws' or a URL beginning with 'http'
```

get_weth.py:

```
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account
from brownie import interface, network, config


def main():
    get_weth()


def get_weth():
    """
    Mints WETH by depositing ETH
    """
    # ABI
    account = get_account()
    # Address
    weth = interface.IWeth(config["networks"][network.show_active()]["weth_token"])
    tx = weth.deposit({"from": account, "value": 0.1 * 10 ** 18})
    tx.wait(1)
    print("Received 0.1 WETH")
    return tx
```

helpful_scripts.py:

```
from brownie import accounts, network, config

LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS = [
    "development",
    "ganache-local",
    "ganache",
    "hardhat",
    "mainnet-fork",
]


def get_account(index=None, id=None):
    if index:
        return accounts[index]
    if (
        network.show_active() in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS
    ):  # if we're on the development network
        return accounts[0]
    if id:
        return accounts.load(id)
    return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])
```

brownie-config.yaml:

```
networks:
  kovan:
    weth_token: '0xd0A1E359811322d97991E03f863a0C30C2cF029C' 
  mainnet-fork: 
    weth_token: '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2' 
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0 
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0'
dotenv: .env
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The message `ValueError: Unknown URI - must be a path to an IPC socket, a websocket beginning with 'ws' or a URL beginning with 'http'` comes from the following section (lines 61-71) of brownies own web3.py (`brownie/network/web3.py`) at

```py
        if self.provider is None:
            if uri.startswith("ws"):
                self.provider = WebsocketProvider(uri, {"close_timeout": timeout})
            elif uri.startswith("http"):
                self.provider = HTTPProvider(uri, {"timeout": timeout})
            else:
                raise ValueError(
                    "Unknown URI - must be a path to an IPC socket, a websocket "
                    "beginning with 'ws' or a URL beginning with 'http'"
                )
```

by adding a `print(uri)` statement just before the `raise ValueError`, I was able to discover that in recreating my new version of the `mainnet-fork` network, I had omitted the scheme of the host URI and had only declared it as 127.0.0.1:8545 (without mentioning http:// ). By deleting the network again as I had already done before and then recreating the network using the command shown below, making sure I declared the host URI in full I was able to resolve this error.

`brownie networks add development mainnet-fork cmd=ganache-cli host=http://127.0.0.1 fork=https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/{my_alchemy_app_url_here} accounts=10 mnemonic=brownie port=8545`